# Updating a value in a method - java

Tags: java

So in this program there are bank accounts and I'm working on a method that allows users to change their balance this is what I have:

```
   public double modifyBalance(int accountID, double adjustment) {
     Account temp = findAccount(accountID, 0, size, lastPos);
     double currBal = temp.getBalance();    
     if (temp!= null){      
        currBal = currBal + adjustment;
     }
     else {
           System.out.println("No account found. ");
        }


     return currBal;
  }
```

the return of currBal however is not updating the actual account's balance, i tried `temp.getBalance() = currBal;` but that didn't work and gave me a compile error saying:

> OrderedVectorOfAccounts.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
>          temp.getBalance = currBal;
>                    ^
>     
> symbol:   variable getBalance
>     location: variable temp of type Account
>   1 error

For example: If the account's balance was 200 and I "deposit" or add 200 it should be 400, but it is remaining as 200 with what I have..
Any help would be great! Thanks!

This is my findAccount():

```
public Account findAccount(int accountID, int from, int to, int [] lastPos){
     if(from > to || (from+2)/2 >= size)
        return null;
     while(from <=to) {   
        if(accountID == theAccounts[(from+to)/2].getAccountNum())
           return theAccounts[(from + to)/2];
        else if (accountID>theAccounts[(from + to)/2].getAccountNum()){
          // return findAccount(accountID, (((from + to)/2)+1), to, lastPos);
           return theAccounts[accountID-1];
        }
        else if (accountID<theAccounts[(from + to)/2].getAccountNum()){
           //return findAccount(accountID, from, (((from + to)/2)-1),lastPos);
           return theAccounts[accountID-1];
        }
     }
     lastPos[0] = (from + to)/2;
     return null;
```

Comment: You're working on a method that allows users to change their balance? I'll take a balance of one billion USD, please.

Comment: Also, you forgot the parentheses at the end of `getBalance()`.

Comment: Its for a project in school lol not a real life application, it's supposed to simulate depositing money at a bank

Comment: Even with them it doesnt work

Comment: Regardless, you might want to consider not making that method `public`.

Comment: The string "doesn't work" is not a built-in error message in Java.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've actually included the line where the error occurred? Which is line 95?

Comment: You should do all monetary calculations using either longs or ints.

Comment: not enough detail -- how are you using this method?  As it is, the method would only return what the adjusted balance *would* be if committed.  But I am supposing that there is some persistence layer (i.e., database access), which would have to be invoked to actually update the account balance with the calculated balance.

Comment: post your findaccount(), you could be returning new Account().

Comment: You will not able to modify the balance with such a code.

Comment: The declaration of (or at least the assignment to) `currBal` needs to be moved inside the `if` block. Otherwise, if `temp` is `null`, the declaration will generate a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

as you have not posted relavant parts of your code, i am assuming either your `temp.getBalance()` is returning `0.0` or your `findAccount()` method returns an empty new `Account()` object.

```
  public Account findAccount(yourparameters) {
      Account account = new Account();
       //do your finding logic
      return account;
```

if say it doesnt find the account, it would still return an Account object , thus

```
     double currBalc= temp.getBalance(); would return 0.0  

 if (temp!= null){  // your if passes here as temp is not null    
    currBal = currBal + adjustment;   0.0+200.0
 }
 else {
       System.out.println("No account found. ");
    }
```

**EDIT after you updated your finfAccount()**

it could be that your call to `getBalance()` is returning 0.0

after    `double currBal = temp.getBalance();` line if it prints you 200.0 then your temp is null.

Comment: My getBalance() has the right balance at the time.. but i'm having trouble updating that to currBal

Comment: in getBalance() theres a private double called currentBalance that is read from a file so i technically need to update currentBalance, but like i said it's private and my professor wants us to keep it that way :\

Comment: do you mean getBalance() has a private variable called currentBalance ??... it cant be true, local variables can only be marked final.

Comment: well the class Account() has the private variable currentBalance and then all getBalance() does is return currentBalance

Answer (score 0):

Your `modifyBalance` method just updates the `currBal` variable, leaving `temp` object intact. This is the reason why `temp`'s `currentBalance` variable is not updated. Why don't you just delete all this mess and create a simple `setBalance` method?

```
public void setBalance(double balance) { this.currentBalance = balance;   }
```

With this you could call anywhere in the code:

```
 Account temp = findAccount(accountID, 0, size, lastPos); 
 if (temp!= null) {   
   temp.setBalance(temp.getBalance() + adjustment); //updates temp currentBalance
 } 
 else { System.out.println("No account found. "); }
```